Tall HTML element still drop to a new page when scaled to fit the A4 page size when printing
I have a long content html, when printing, the height of the element will exceed the A4 paper size, and will print 2 pages.
If I add transform: scale to the element to force the content to shrink to fit the A4 paper size it works on Chrome 100

but on Chrome 120+ and new Edge, the new page still appears event when the HTML element is scaled.
Content is still split into 2 pages on Chrome 120+ or Edge:

How to deal with it? How can I properly scale the page to fit the A4 paper.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    @media print {
      .page-container {
        height: 292mm;
        width: 205mm;
        padding: 16mm 16mm;
        overflow: visible;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        transform-origin: top center;
      }
      
      body {
        height: 292mm;
        width: 205mm;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-container" style="transform:scale(0.65)">
    <div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nunc purus. Cras sit amet dapibus dolor. Praesent commodo tristique est. Phasellus vehicula ac nisl rutrum feugiat. Quisque volutpat sollicitudin neque, a sodales nisl porttitor eget. Sed aliquet purus cursus magna volutpat auctor. Maecenas vitae porttitor nisl, ut posuere turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent consectetur lectus ac ligula mollis vehicula. Donec ac ex in felis mattis egestas non sit amet mauris. Fusce rhoncus euismod est, nec pulvinar nibh mattis vel. Etiam tempor, tellus non efficitur porttitor, leo leo molestie tortor, ac malesuada est arcu at turpis. Curabitur a augue sed diam iaculis pretium.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse orci nunc, lobortis sed scelerisque nec, rutrum sit amet leo. Donec ut neque non eros lacinia convallis. Proin vitae mauris ac mi vestibulum tincidunt. Duis consectetur auctor felis, non congue erat ultricies quis. In ipsum neque, ornare at pulvinar et, luctus id lectus. Nunc dignissim lectus in dui sagittis maximus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras posuere libero vitae odio bibendum consectetur. Integer sit amet convallis turpis. Nullam consequat nisl nibh, nec varius felis hendrerit id. Morbi ullamcorper dolor sit amet hendrerit tincidunt. Phasellus viverra erat tellus, a lobortis justo vulputate sit amet.

Suspendisse hendrerit metus enim, aliquam blandit diam vulputate sit amet. Mauris sapien nisl, finibus sit amet erat et, maximus finibus nisi. Maecenas aliquet lacus eu mauris posuere vulputate. Pellentesque nec bibendum leo. Integer tempor porttitor porta. Etiam fringilla, enim non porttitor elementum, ex elit consequat nisi, in fermentum neque felis eget ante. Integer ac mauris orci. Ut non tincidunt neque. Vivamus ac rhoncus tellus. Ut commodo mattis libero eu fringilla. Nunc luctus non dui at condimentum. Maecenas in odio imperdiet, sagittis mi pellentesque, posuere eros. Donec lacinia nibh sagittis, consequat massa a, tincidunt mi. Cras nec mattis odio. Aliquam finibus euismod neque. Curabitur est ipsum, tempor in augue eget, commodo scelerisque ipsum.

Vivamus efficitur velit vel lectus accumsan cursus. Ut enim quam, blandit non eros ac, interdum congue mi. Proin bibendum justo nec turpis pretium facilisis. Aliquam vel nunc auctor, consectetur sapien non, luctus erat. Proin dapibus, ligula quis congue mattis, augue mi sollicitudin ante, et posuere ante augue sit amet lectus. Sed ullamcorper, odio eu placerat fermentum, velit lectus dictum orci, id pretium mauris tortor sit amet purus. Pellentesque ut scelerisque orci, quis scelerisque neque.

Nullam ornare odio mi, sit amet lobortis magna laoreet ut. Ut sed ornare dolor, eget porttitor nibh. Sed placerat, purus ut dignissim porta, ante augue sollicitudin massa, nec maximus nulla eros vel leo. Duis feugiat a justo eget luctus. Sed vitae urna ut ante rhoncus laoreet. Vestibulum accumsan ultrices arcu, vitae gravida metus tincidunt vitae. Vestibulum mollis ipsum ipsum, sit amet luctus ipsum congue vitae. Nulla ex augue, imperdiet nec dapibus at, pulvinar ac lorem. Cras vitae nibh urna. Vestibulum sed diam hendrerit, accumsan enim vel, volutpat sem. Nunc placerat condimentum justo, ut egestas lacus varius in. Donec maximus at metus nec aliquet. Sed semper, augue vitae maximus ullamcorper, diam quam fringilla mi, non dapibus felis augue vel quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras vitae venenatis ex, pellentesque maximus metus. Morbi quis molestie mi.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam in nunc purus. Cras sit amet dapibus dolor. Praesent commodo tristique est. Phasellus vehicula ac nisl rutrum feugiat. Quisque volutpat sollicitudin neque, a sodales nisl porttitor eget. Sed aliquet purus cursus magna volutpat auctor. Maecenas vitae porttitor nisl, ut posuere turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent consectetur lectus ac ligula mollis vehicula. Donec ac ex in felis mattis egestas non sit amet mauris. Fusce rhoncus euismod est, nec pulvinar nibh mattis vel. Etiam tempor, tellus non efficitur porttitor, leo leo molestie tortor, ac malesuada est arcu at turpis. Curabitur a augue sed diam iaculis pretium.

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse orci nunc, lobortis sed scelerisque nec, rutrum sit amet leo. Donec ut neque non eros lacinia convallis. Proin vitae mauris ac mi vestibulum tincidunt. Duis consectetur auctor felis, non congue erat ultricies quis. In ipsum neque, ornare at pulvinar et, luctus id lectus. Nunc dignissim lectus in dui sagittis maximus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras posuere libero vitae odio bibendum consectetur. Integer sit amet convallis turpis. Nullam consequat nisl nibh, nec varius felis hendrerit id. Morbi ullamcorper dolor sit amet hendrerit tincidunt. Phasellus viverra erat tellus, a lobortis justo vulputate sit amet.

Suspendisse hendrerit metus enim, aliquam blandit diam vulputate sit amet. Mauris sapien nisl, finibus sit amet erat et, maximus finibus nisi. Maecenas aliquet lacus eu mauris posuere vulputate. Pellentesque nec bibendum leo. Integer tempor porttitor porta. Etiam fringilla, enim non porttitor elementum, ex elit consequat nisi, in fermentum neque felis eget ante. Integer ac mauris orci. Ut non tincidunt neque. Vivamus ac rhoncus tellus. Ut commodo mattis libero eu fringilla. Nunc luctus non dui at condimentum. Maecenas in odio imperdiet, sagittis mi pellentesque, posuere eros. Donec lacinia nibh sagittis, consequat massa a, tincidunt mi. Cras nec mattis odio. Aliquam finibus euismod neque. Curabitur est ipsum, tempor in augue eget, commodo scelerisque ipsum.

Vivamus efficitur velit vel lectus accumsan cursus. Ut enim quam, blandit non eros ac, interdum congue mi. Proin bibendum justo nec turpis pretium facilisis. Aliquam vel nunc auctor, consectetur sapien non, luctus erat. Proin dapibus, ligula quis congue mattis, augue mi sollicitudin ante, et posuere ante augue sit amet lectus. Sed ullamcorper, odio eu placerat fermentum, velit lectus dictum orci, id pretium mauris tortor sit amet purus. Pellentesque ut scelerisque orci, quis scelerisque neque.

Nullam ornare odio mi, sit amet lobortis magna laoreet ut. Ut sed ornare dolor, eget porttitor nibh. Sed placerat, purus ut dignissim porta, ante augue sollicitudin massa, nec maximus nulla eros vel leo. Duis feugiat a justo eget luctus. Sed vitae urna ut ante rhoncus laoreet. Vestibulum accumsan ultrices arcu, vitae gravida metus tincidunt vitae. Vestibulum mollis ipsum ipsum, sit amet luctus ipsum congue vitae. Nulla ex augue, imperdiet nec dapibus at, pulvinar ac lorem. Cras vitae nibh urna. Vestibulum sed diam hendrerit, accumsan enim vel, volutpat sem. Nunc placerat condimentum justo, ut egestas lacus varius in. Donec maximus at metus nec aliquet. Sed semper, augue vitae maximus ullamcorper, diam quam fringilla mi, non dapibus felis augue vel quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras vitae venenatis ex, pellentesque maximus metus. Morbi quis molestie mi.    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




This question is similar to: Scale HTML to fit one page when printing. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
